# option to change jquery ui datepicker to just a "yearpicker"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm checking [datapicker documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#options) here trying to find a way to change it from a full display date picker to just something where I can pick a year only. But I can't find anything. I tried suggestions found here like this, but it still displays the full view.

```
.datepicker({changeDay:false, changeMonth:false, changeYear:true})
```

Can I somehow turn the datapicker to a year picker only?

Comment: Wouldn't a `<select></select>` suffice?

Comment: @Andrew Hare I'm just trying to keep them consistent because I have other datepickers and use the same style for all of them. It would be nice if it were possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my company's website, we used jQuery UI slider instead since year is a single value. In our implementation, we also had to do a year range, a slider also accommodated for that.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps