# jquery UI datepicker hide day picker

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, datepicker

So this has been answered before. Since im merly familiar with css im abit lost here. I have 2 datepickers. With code

```
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

both datepickers lose day-picking option. But I would like to keep it on the second one (`name="datepicker1" id = "datepicker1"`).
I have tried

```
<style>  
    #datepicker.ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

but it doesn't do anything. datepicker i'd like to remove is:
`<div  id="datepicker" name="datepicker"></div>`

Edit: I wan't to keep month and year picking option and remove daypicking option from first datepicker. 
 I have helped myself with [jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only) , but i can't find solution on how to hide only one of datepickers' daypicking option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093948/option-to-change-jquery-ui-datepicker-to-just-a-yearpicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest putting a space between `#datepicker` and `.ui-datepicker-calendar`, otherwise it will only select items that have the id AND the class.

Comment: Alright that solved it. Tahnks. Gonna set it as answer in a min.

Answer (score 0):

There should be method 'hide'. Look into official documentations: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-hide.

Comment: that hides whole datepicker, right? I guess I wasn't clear enough, I want to keep month and year picking option and remove daypicking